# Parsing xml/svg

Tags: python, xml, svg

Why is this not printing all the paths only the first instance/tag?

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def converter():
 xmldoc= minidom.parse("file.svg")
 a=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
 b=a.getElementsByTagName("g")[0]
 pth=b.getElementsByTagName("path")

 for p in pth:
      a = p.getAttribute('class')
      b = p.getAttribute('d')

      return a , b
```

```html
<g id="group">
<path
class="pp-region pp-Citiesregi2014 pp-citis-nro-666"
d="
M 455385.23 7717427.99
L 457750.49 7722100.53
L 458363.99 7725704.59
L 458364 7725704.64
L 457375.58 7730965.44
L 458418.95 7732463.37
L 460373.42 7735446.16
L 464487.75 7738223.56
L 467881.88 7741720.66
L 469719.4 7745286.72
z" />
```

So i would only need the class pp-citis-nro-666 and its correspondig value. This applied to all the elements.

Comment: do you have more than one `<g>`-tag?

Comment: It would be best if you could include a minimized snippet of XML that would reproduce this issue (or the whole *file.svg*) if it's small.

Comment: I've updated the original post

Comment: Are there multiple `<path>` tags within a `<g>` tag set?

Comment: Yes and all structured as above